# how to force the refresh everytime when click the menu

Tags: react-admin

im new to coding/react-admin and english

im trying to make Datagrid column looks better, so I tried to use *headerClassName* to change width.

and the problem is styles(width) are won't change until I refresh(F5) I don't know why tho.

so what am i missing or is there way to refresh the page when change the menu?

Comment: please provide more details/code

Comment: do you mean refresh as in browser refresh or do you want to fetch the data again?

Comment: I mean refresh as browser, ill add code soon wait for about a day please sorry